# apache 2.4 proxyerroroverride for custom 503 but not 404

Tags: apache-2.4, custom-errors

We have a tomcat application that has a nicely formatted and functional 404 page.  We were using Apache 2.2 as a front end, and overrode the error pages for 502 and 503 error conditions using the ErrorDocument directive for those two codes.  In order to get that to work, we had to include the ProxyErrorOverride On directive.  When we upgraded to Apache 2.4, we started getting a standard Apache 404 page (since we didn't provide an ErrorDocument directive for the 404 code).  Commenting out the ProxyErrorOverride directive, we get the tomcat application's 404 content.  Of course, we also get the standard 502 and 503 pages rather than our desired custom responses.  How do we get our custom 502 and 503 pages without losing the application's 404?